# return view() doesn't work in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm getting `Use of undefined constant dashboard - assumed 'dashboard'`
after

```
public function login()
    {
        $email = Input::get('email');
        $password = Input::get('password');

        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password]))
        {
            return view(dashboard);
        }
        else
            return 'nope';

    }
```

It was working when in my subscriber model I had

```
Class Subscriber extends Model
```

But after changing that to

```
class Subscriber extends \Eloquent implements Authenticatable
```

returning `view()` in controller no longer works.

Comment: What error happens when you put quotes around `dashboard` like the error says you should?

Comment: omg stupid mistake. got it

Answer (score 3):

Your error is saying that `dashboard` is undefined.  The error also suggests that you try quoting dashboard, like so:

`'dashboard'`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the quotes around dashboard.

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password]))
{
  return view('dashboard');
}
```

If dashboard is nested within a folder mention it likewise:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password]))
{
  return view('folderName.dashboard');
}
```